devide values with JSONata
JSONata is honestly driving me crazy. I asked something similar a couple of weeks ago, but I still don't know what I'm doing so here I am again.
What I'm working with:
[[  {
    "time": "2024-04-26",
    "value": 40
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-27",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-28",
    "value": 20
  }
],
[  {
    "time": "2024-04-26",
    "value_2": 5
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-27",
    "value_2": 2
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-28",
    "value_2": 4
  }
]]

What I want is to get the distinct values for time and devide the values - value/value_2:
[  {
    "time": "2024-04-26",
    "value": 8
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-27",
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-28",
    "value": 5
  }
]


I tried something like this but I only get the distinct values for time.
$type($) = 'array' ? 
(($count($) ) > 0 ? 
$map($[0], function($v, $i, $a) 
{ { "time": $v.time, 
"value": $v.value/ $v.value_2 } })[]: []): undefined 


Output:
[
  {
    "time": "2024-04-26"
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-27"
  },
  {
    "time": "2024-04-28"
  }
]


unfortunately I still need help with this

How about this:
(
  /* convert the array to an map of date to value */
  $first := $[0].{time: value};
  $second := $[1].{time: value_2};

  /* iterate over the keys, lookup the values
  $keys($first).{
      "time": $,
      "value": $lookup($first, $) / $lookup($second, $)
  }
)


thank you!! i just tested it and it works just as I needed it

This is ugly but it works
(
     $obj := $;

     $distinct(time) 
     ~> $map(function($v, $i, $a) {
     {$v: {"value": $[time = $v].(value), "value_2": $[time = $v].(value_2)}}
     }) 
     ~> $map(function($v, $i, $a) { $v.*.(value/value_2) })

)
https://try.jsonata.org/8cTvSB0Ai
